# Is there any proper autocomplete and/or syntax checker for CoffeeScript in vim?

Tags: vimscript

Is there any proper autocomplete and/or syntax checker for `CoffeeScript` in vim?

This is not a very complex question but i cant seem to find anything.
I am currently using YCM.

Comment: Not sure about "proper", but [syntastic](https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic) does support linting with `coffee` and `coffeelint`.  If you have suggestions for other linters post to the [issue tracker](https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic/issues).

Comment: @lcd047 Well there are some guessing plugins. That are not strictly for coffeescript but sort of help and these help with the tags and autofilling not syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't code in CoffeeScript myself, but I've used [vim-coffee-script](https://github.com/kchmck/vim-coffee-script) for viewing files.

It doesn't support autocomplete, but it kind of provides syntax checking by compiling (showing the errors) and running [coffeelint](http://www.coffeelint.org/). I know it's kind of a stretch though.. maybe better than nothing?